# vanilla javascript onload click simulation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure this...
I have a that is being fed by some javascript for a server, and when using jquery things don't work at all, so I have to stick to vanilla javascript ..

What I am trying to do is load a page which always defaults to the first tab out of three but instead of defaulting to the first tab, i want it to trigger a fake simulated click to load the 3rd tab.

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

the javascript that is been fed, automatically writes an inline style of "display:table-row" to the active panel, and a display:none to the panel 3 of the tab system.

So i can't figure out without using jquery how to simulate a fake click or force it to make tab 3 active, and to make panel 3 display;table row

Edit: I used this code

```
var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    // Create our event (with options)
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
var someLink = document.querySelector('#panel3');
simulateClick();
```

I forgot to add the java code i tried to use.

Comment: Post relevant JavaScript but before you do that please read this: [mcve]

Comment: forgot to include it.

Comment: Are you sure the `a` you want to click has `id="panel3"`? Are you waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` before trying to dispatch the `click` event? Also, you're not passing `someLink` to `simulateClick();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking is not needed. Once the page is loaded and the server has done whatever it was tasked to do, run your script. This is normally done by placing a `<script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag. Details are commented in demo.

```js
const setActive = targetIndex => {
  /*
  Collect all <a> into a HTMLCollection then convert
  to an Array.
  */
  const linx = Array.from(document.links);

  // Collect all panels into a NodeList
  const panels = document.querySelectorAll('section');

  /* Iterate through the NodeList...
  A - for...of loop using .entries() which returns the
      array [index, value] which we easily access by
      destructuring
  B - Find the current <li>
  C - On each iteration if the current index does not
      equal the given targetIndex then remove .active
      class from <li> and set display: none to style of
      current <section>
  D - Otherwise add .active class and set style to
      display: table-row
  */
  for (let [index, link] of linx.entries()) { //A
    let item = link.parentElement; //B
    if (index != targetIndex) { //C
      item.classList.remove('active');
      panels[index].style.display = "none";
    } else { //D
      item.classList.add('active');
      panels[index].style.display = "table-row";
    }
  }
  return false;
}

setActive(2);
```

```css
/* Added to prove .active (just for demo -- not required) */

.active {
  outline: 3px dashed #f00
}

ul {
  list-style: none
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px
}

main {
  display: table
}

section {
  display: table-row
}

section * {
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<main>
  <section id='panel1'>
    <h3>Panel 1</h3>
  </section>
  <section id='panel2'>
    <h3>Panel 2</h3>
  </section>
  <section id='panel3'>
    <h3>Panel 3</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```